# Searchbar subview in UICollectionView delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uicollectionview

I am trying to add a searchbar into my collectionview so that it disappears when the user swipes down the collectionview to view the cell and images.

I am able to add the searchbar without any problems, but when I try to hook up the delegate, I get a crash:

```
 -[UICollectionReusableView searchBar]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb30bc627f0
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UICollectionReusableView searchBar]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb30bc627f0'
```

The interface for my first view, the main view's class looks like:

@interface OKPhotoGalleryViewController ()

Here is some code for my viewDidLoad method:

```
[self.flickrCollectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:NSStringFromClass([OKSearchBarPhotoGalleryViewCell class]) bundle:nil] forSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:@"SearchBar"];

    UISearchBar *searchBar;
    [self.flickrCollectionView addSubview:searchBar];
```

And here is my viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind method that is required:

```
- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *searchBarIdentifier = @"SearchBar";
    OKSearchBarPhotoGalleryViewCell *collectionViewSearchBar = (OKSearchBarPhotoGalleryViewCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:searchBarIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    collectionViewSearchBar.searchBar.delegate = self;

    return collectionViewSearchBar;
}
```

where my application crashes on the line

```
collectionViewSearchBar.searchBar.delegate = self;
```

and my class' header that I am instantiating and adding as a subview inside of my UICollectionView looks like:

```
@interface OKSearchBarPhotoGalleryViewCell : UICollectionReusableView

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchBar;

@end
```

I've tried changing the class names, because at first it was searchbar.searchbar.delegate = self, and I thought that could've caused some problems, but it didn't help. I tried to hook up the delegate to the searchbar in my OKSearchBarPhotoGalleryViewCell, but I still received the same crash.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this last night by creating a searchbar, putting it in the right place, hooking up the delegate and then adding it on my subview. Works like a charm and all the searchBar delegate methods sends me messages correctly.

```
    - (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *searchBarIdentifier = @"SearchBar";
    OKSearchBarPhotoGalleryViewCell *collectionViewSearchBar = (OKSearchBarPhotoGalleryViewCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:searchBarIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(collectionView.frame), 44)];
    searchBar.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    searchBar.delegate = self;

    [collectionViewSearchBar addSubview:searchBar];
    return collectionViewSearchBar;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, i have another way,simpler one..

Step 1) Add  delegate for your tableView's scrolling `scrollViewDidScroll`.

step 2) Now get scrolled-down or scrolled-up by comparing `lastScrollContentOffeset`(CGFloat) with `scrollView.contentOffset.y`

```
   Also update lastSCrollContentOffeset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
```

Step 3) Now, depending on ScrollUP OR ScrollDown , show/hide Text field or other view's as required...

Note. You can also animate show/hide transition of your view.

Important. If you are adding search bar on top of Collection View ,then add use TopConstraint for collectionView . Modify this constraint as you show/hide view's

This is working solution.